# boolan algebra - deriving the conditional expression using AND/OR is tricky part

Tags: javascript

Working on this problem.

The basic rule for validating a leap year are as follows:
 
- Most years that can be divided evenly by 4 are leap years.

 - Exception: Century years are NOT leap years UNLESS they can be evenly divided by 400.

This is the answer:

```
if(y%4==0 && y%100!=0 || y%400==0){return true}
```

I understand the different parts : `y%4==0, y%100!=0, y%400==0`. But getting mixed up on how to use the AND/OR together.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: AND binds more tightly than OR; think multiplication versus addition: `2*x+5` is `(2*x)+5` and not `2*(x+5)`. Same here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a leap year check. In which case, you should be doing the following:

```
if ((y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || y % 400 == 0) {
    return true;
}
```

This ensures that your first bit of logic is checked first. Only if the initial bracket (with the &&) is false, then the modulus 400 will then be checked.

Comment: In fact, I'd just do: `return (y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 !=0) || y % 400 == 0;` in an isLeapYear(int year) function.

Comment: The parentheses are correct and many would argue that they're helpful, but strictly speaking they are not necessary because `&&` binds more tightly than `||` and the evaluation order without the added parentheses is exactly the same.

Comment: I would argue though that explicit is always better than implicit.

Comment: I do not disagree but I don't have strong feelings on the topic :)